# Appfog "af update" Permisson denied Error

Tags: ruby, node.js, google-chrome, updates, appfog

I'm using appfog that is application server service with a cloud.

When it comes to my problem, I'm create new app (node.js project) and trying to upload my project files with Af CLI Tool (on Ruby) but get an error (Permisson denied) also if running Google Chrome, I get the error:

> Permission denied - ./AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cache/data_0

If turn off Google Chrome I get the error "Permission denied - Read". Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the path of the project because by default updater you try to project your filepath: //C:/Users/userName.